# Photoshop (August 2021 update) - export for multiple sizes adding unwanted numbers to filenames?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

If exporting assets via the Export As dialog, and choosing multiple sizes as pictured, Photoshop is now (as of very recently) adding incremented numbers to saved files.

For instance, if I did this before, I would end up with:

```
icon-platter.png
icon-platter@2x.png
```

This is good. But NOW, I end up with:

```
icon-platter.png
icon-platter-1@2x.png
```

This is super annoying and blows up a process I've been using for a couple of years now.

I know this is a shot in the dark, but does anybody know of any setting or hack to make this stop happening?

<sub>I cannot fathom why adobe does these things. Drives me (and everyone else, I'm sure) crazy.</sub>

[image: The Export As dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

At the moment of writing, you can fall back to the previous version of the Export dialog by changing a preference setting in PS.

Go to Preferences > Export, and down at the bottom there should be a checkbox option:

`Use Legacy 'Export As'`

Enable that, and that's it, it stops the dumb behavior.

As an aside: it also returns the ability to set a quality percentage for JPGs when exporting. The newer dialog only gives you Low/Medium/High etc, while the old one let you specify a number, like 70%. So, this solves that issue as well!